# How to resolve Exception of Admin User installation issue while Theme Updating

Tags: magento2.3, theme, magento-community, static-content-deploy

I'm getting error during executing site/themesetup (via browser).

The updation regarding modules happened properly & quickly, but it is encountering error While installing a new admin user(unsure why it is trying to install admin user, while theme update).

Due to incomplete themesetup, my site was stuck in maintenance mode, so I disabled maintenance mode, however, the site is still broken(loading without any theme related CSS)

```
..
..
Module 'Yotpo_Yotpo':

Installing admin user...
[ERROR] Exception: An existing user has the given username but different email. Username and email both need to match an existing user or both be new. in ..public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/AdminAccount.php:202
Stack trace:
#0 ..public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/AdminAccount.php(113): Magento\Setup\Model\AdminAccount->validateUserMatches()
#1 ..public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/AdminAccount.php(83): Magento\Setup\Model\AdminAccount->saveAdminUser()
#2 ..public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1175): Magento\Setup\Model\AdminAccount->save()
#3 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installAdminUser(Array)
#4 ..public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(367): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 ..public_html/themesetup/src/Codazon/Setup/Controller/Install.php(181): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#6 ..public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(84): Codazon\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#7 ..public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 ..public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#9 ..public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(116): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 ..public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#11 ..public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 ..public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#13 ..public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 ..public_html/themesetup/index22.php(35): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#15 ..public_html/themesetup/index.php(17): include('/home/customer/...')
#16 {main}
```

Further if i run setup:upgrade, di:compile there are no errors
however, if i run deploy:static i get following error.

```
frontend/Theme/Sub_Theme/en_US 2441/2663 =========================>-- 91% 11 secs
Compilation from source: ../public_html/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ../public_html/vendor/wikimedia/less.php/lib/Less/Tree/Value.php on line 26

In File.php line 151:

The contents from the "../public_html/pub/static/frontend/Theme/Sub_Theme/en_US/mage/gallery/gallery.min.css" fi
le can't be read. Warning!file_get_contents(../public_html/pub/static/frontend/Theme/Sub_Theme/en_US/mage/galler
y/gallery.min.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

setup:static-content:deploy [-f|--force] [-s|--strategy [STRATEGY]] [-a|--area [AREA]] [--exclude-area [EXCLUDE-AREA]] [-t|--theme [THEME]] [--exclude-theme [EXCLUDE-THEME]] [-l|--language [LANGUAGE]] [--exclude-language [EXCLUDE-LANGUAGE]] [-j|--jobs [JOBS]] [--max-execution-time [MAX-EXECUTION-TIME]] [--symlink-locale] [--content-version CONTENT-VERSION] [--refresh-content-version-only] [--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images] [--no-fonts] [--no-html] [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [--] [<languages>...]
```

How can I fix above issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1-`php bin/magento c:c` 
2-`php bin/magento c:f` 
3-`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
4-`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` 
5- `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
6- set required permission to var and pub/media folders

Comment: hi, I had tried that before posting here, (as these commands are my basic toolkit commands, that i run when any issue happens.)